# How to make manual alternative to List<> class

Tags: c#, class, collections

I need to make alternative to List<> class where I will have 4 methods... Two for adding `int` items, one from front, other from behind and two for deleting, one from front and other from behind as well. My class should not inherit anything.

Something like this...

```
public class MyList
{
    public void AddItemsFront(int pItem)
    {

    }

    public void AddItemsBehind(int pItem)
    {

    }

    public void DeleteItemsFront(int pItem)
    {

    }

    public void DeleteItemsBehind(int pItem)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is called a Deque.

Comment: Well.... why don't start writing your class and ask for *specific* question when you're stuck? Actually your question lacks question itself, noone here will write this class for you, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I am not sure how to start... Any pseudo code would be fine. @AndyKorneyev

Comment: Store the values in an array. Keep track of a head index and a tail index. Resize the array when it is full. That's the basic gist. You can always look at the source code for `Queue<T>` to see how they implement a one-ended queue. It's trivial to turn it into a double-ended queue.

Comment: Or take a look here to see how a Queue works: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/QueueArray.html

Comment: every answer is useful. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hold an instance of a `List<T>` in a field, `List<T>` has already these methods:

```
public class MyList<T>
{
    private List<T> _TheList;
    public MyList()
    {
        _TheList = new List<T>();
    }
    public List<T> TheList { get { return _TheList; } set { _TheList = value; } }

    public void AddItemFront(T pItem)
    {
        TheList.Insert(0, pItem);
    }

    public void AddItemBehind(T pItem)
    {
        TheList.Add(pItem);
    }

    public void DeleteItemFront()
    {
        TheList.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    public void DeleteItemBehind()
    {
        TheList.RemoveAt(TheList.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Since it's a generic  class you could also use it for different types than `int`.

```
var myList = new MyList<int>();
myList.AddItemFront(1);
```

Comment: Perfect! Vote up. @Tim

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that's got a data member of the correct `List<>` type, and implement your methods by calling the appropriate methods on the `List<>` data member. You will want your `delete` operations to return the object they removed from the list.

This is often referred to as the Adapter pattern. [Wikipedia has a page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).