# How to manually make a alternative object to List<> object

Tags: c#, list, object, collections

Today I posted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501129/how-to-make-manual-alternative-to-list-class) and I though my problem is solved. After a conversation related to that question, I realized that I need to make my own `object` which will look like `List<int>` and to define my own methods (Insert, Add etc...). The problem I am facing might be theoretical thing to face, but on the other side, I think some code will help. I can not imagine how my new defined object should look a like well familiar `List<>` and its methods. Any suggestion will be gratefully accepted. Here is some code... I hope I will not be misunderstood.

```
public class MyDefinedList
    {
        private object _MyDefinedList;

        public MyDefinedList()
        {
            _MyDefinedList = new MyDefinedList();
        }

        public void AddItemFront(int pItem)
        {
            _MyDefinedList.Insert(0, pItem);
        }

        public void AddItemBehind(int pItem)
        {
            _MyDefinedList.Add(pItem);
        }

        public void DeleteItemFront()
        {
            _MyDefinedList.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        public void DeleteItemBehind()
        {
            _MyDefinedList.RemoveAt();
        }

        private void Insert(int pStart, int p)
        { 

        }

        private void Add(int pItem)
        {

        }

        private void RemoveAt()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably you want to implement, `IList<T>` interface?

Comment: You have already accepted your answer in the previous question. How does this question differ from your last question?

Comment: I used there List<T>. Here, I need to make my own object with methods... @FINDarkside

Comment: MyList<T> is your own object with methods.

Comment: Go with Dmitry's answer. He's nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is implementing `IList<T>` interface, i.e.

```
  public class MyDefinedList: IList<T> {
    // back ground list that actually stores the data
    private List<T> m_List = new List<T>();

    ...

    public void Add(T item) {
      m_List.Add(item); // Nothing to write home about
    }

    public void DeleteItemFront() {
      m_List.RemoveAt(0);
    } 

    ...
  }
```

So `MyDefinedList` works as `List<T>` (it implements `IList<T>`) while having some extra methods. Another way is implementing *extension methods* on `List<T>` (so every `List<T>` now *has* `DeleteItemFront` method):

```
  public static class ListExtensions {
    public void DeleteItemFront<T>(this IList<T> list) {
      if (null == list) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));  

      list.RemoveAt(0);
    } 
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently wrapping your class around.. itself:

```
public class MyDefinedList
{
    private object _MyDefinedList;

    public MyDefinedList()
    {
        _MyDefinedList = new MyDefinedList();
    }        
}
```

Creating instance of this class if not possible. Each instance of `MyDefinedList` will create new instance of `MyDefinedList`, which will create new instance of `MyDefinedList` etc. Result - StackOverflowException. But even if it will be possible, where do you think implementation of collection will appear? It will not magically appear after you create `MyDefinedList` 1000 times. You have three options:

1. Take instance of something which is already implemented. I.e. you should wrap your class around instance of some collection class which already have similar functionality, but different interface. Google for *Adapter* pattern. Also you can use extension method here.
2. Extend something which is already implemented. I.e. inherit from some collection class and add methods which you need.
3. Write your own implementation. You can use arrays, create some linked lists etc.

If you'll go for first option, then you can wrap your class around list:

```
  private List<int> _innerList;
```

Consider also inheriting from `List<int>` (second option):

```
public class MyDefinedList : List<int>
{
    public void AddItemFront (int pItem)
    {
        Insert(0, pItem);
    }

    public void AddItemBehind (int pItem)
    {
        Add(pItem);
    }

    public void DeleteItemFront()
    {
        if (Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        RemoveAt(0);
    }

    public void DeleteItemBehind()
    {
        if (Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        RemoveAt(Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should not inherit anything and also not use anything which already exist. It should be done from scratch. @sergey

Comment: @Jack Dawson Why? If you really must do everything from scratch, the you use arrays and make them larger manually when you add items.

Comment: That is the task. Don't ask me why... :) @FINDarkside

Comment: No. I want to get a tip or anything similar, perhaps a theoretical approach. Something to start with. @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: @JackDawson you need to answer why if you want correct\helpful answer...It looks like you just want to know how List<T> class is implemented and you want to replicate the logic and create your class....so you can just check out the source code....Microsoft has aldready made that public...why are you posting it as question

Comment: @JackDawson then correct answer is [go and investigate source of List implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646). After that you can write your own class or copy-paste implementation and use it.

Comment: OK. My task is to measure execution time of filling array, List<int> etc with some data. After I did that, I got an answer that I need to make my own object similar to List<int> and to measure that too. My data are electrical signals. @Viru

Comment: @JackDawson your question is extremely broad and unclear. SO works this way - you should understand your task and start implementing. If you face some problem (error or unexpected results) then you post your code and ask for help. Currently your problem is self-referencing class which you are writing (and I pointed in answer how to solve it). But as I see your real problem is that you don't understand your task. Because you didn't start solving it.

Answer (score 0):

So basically as other guys, I don't understand why you can't just use built in collection types (maybe it's some interview task). Anyway you can read about indexers in C#:
[Indexers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)